# Как можно программно изменить марджин у моего view элемента?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Не спорю что вопрос довольно простой и понятный но решить я эту проблему не смог. Есть такая разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".jobAGENT.JobsList">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/no_jobs"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh_t"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/job_list_t"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    <com.github.loadingview.LoadingView
        android:id="@+id/loadingView"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:lv_duration="15"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:lv_end_color="@color/color_end"
        app:lv_external_radius="24dp"
        app:lv_internal_radius="4dp"
        app:lv_start_color="@color/color_start" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

я хочу при определенном условии менять марджин списка и/или refresh_layout и показывать лоадер. То есть нужно приподнять список таким образом что-бы последний элемент не обрезало. Зачем я это делаю - при достижении нижней точки списка я подгружаю данные в список, и чтобы показать что идет процесс загрузки я хочу показывать прогрес бар, а когда ответ сервера будет удачный то скрывать его. Вот как я приподнимаю refreshLayout:

```
val param = refreshLayout.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
param.setMargins(5, 10, 5, 150)
refreshLayout.layoutParams = param
```

меня смущает конечно что марджин нижний 150, но может это и правильно. Этот способ поднимает контейнер с списком, но обрезает последний элемент списка. Вот как я вообще поднимаю список с условием:

```
if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                        loader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        loader.start()
                        val param = refreshLayout.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                        param.setMargins(5, 10, 5, 150)
                        refreshLayout.layoutParams = param
                    } else {
                        val param = refreshLayout.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                        param.setMargins(5, 10, 5, 5)
                        refreshLayout.layoutParams = param
                    }
```

можно ли как-то сделать это по-нормальному а не так как я это сделал?)

Comment: Я когда только начинал изучать Android встретился с похожей проблемой, и адекватного решения я тогда не нашел. А когда встретил приложения с двумя PrograssBar  в одном списке (один сверху, другой снизу), вовсе забросил эту идею, так как это "плохой опыт пользователя", может стоит найти другое решение? Второй вариант, зачем двигать контейнер со списком? Почему бы индикатор загрузки не выдвигать поверх вашего списка?

Comment: это как поверх? типа диалогом? я думал вообще менять содержимое itema но это походу тоже идея не очень, в итого решил так делать, хочется сделать что-то на подобии paging library, но полегче, вот застопорился с лоадером

Comment: Обычно разметка пишется так, что скрываешь\показываешь какие-то ее части, а она сама адаптируется\двигает другие части. Никакие отступы программно менять не стоит, только visibility.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, ну вот я настроил и у меня все-равно обрезает последний элемент списка, можно этого как-то избежать?

Comment: Можно конечно, написав правильную разметку. Берите Layout Inspector и ищите, что и почему "обрезает": https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: Еще замечание: setMargins() в пикселях, а разметка в dp. Об этом нужно всегда помнить.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, вот я тоже над этим задумался, почему такие числа ставить приходится. А к чему использовать layout inspector - к item списка или к главному макету где висит список?

Comment: По поводу пикселей и dp всегда используйте преобразование: 150 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density. Разные экраны разные смещения, а так всё будет гуд. Во вторых я сейчас в основном использую ConstraintLayout и потому у меня не возникает вопросов кто кого двигает. Там одна вью над другой располагается без проблем. Если взять за идею мысль Жени, то тогда вам стоит расположить индикатор загрузки, выставить ему значение gone, и закрыть всё поле Списком, после установки значения VISIBLE индикатору он список сдвинет на столько на сколько ему это нужно будет (наверное)

Comment: @Valeriy, я просто сейчас добавил все чтобы работало показывание бара и в итоге иногда скрывается все работает корректно и скрывается четко последний item списка а бывает такое что может скрыться еще немного больше чем нужно, но вообще это очень плохонькая идея как сделать аналог paging library :)

Comment: Не знаю, я ещё так глубоко не рыл, если вы там это видели, почему же вам его не использовать? Что интересно, я уже давно не видел прогрессбаров подгрузки списка, только что попробовал в Gmail  с выключенным интернетом и его там не оказалось...

Comment: да в gmail просто грузит список и все, хотя раньше по-моему был